# Boxplot in SAS using proc gchart

Tags: sas

First question, is it possible to produce a boxplot using proc gchart in SAS?

If it is possible, please give me a brief idea.

Or else, on the topic of using proc boxplot.
Suppose I have a dataset that has three variables ID score year;
something like,

```
data aaa;
input id score year;
datalines;
1 50 2008
1 40 2007
2 30 2008
2 20 2007
;
run;
```

I want to produce a boxplot showing for each ID in each year. (So in this case, 4 boxplots in a single plot)
How can i achieve this?

I have tried using

```
proc boxplot data=aaa;
plot score*ID;
by year;
run;
```

However, this is not working as we can see year is not sorted by order.
Is there a way to get other this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to sort your input dataset first. Run this

```
proc sort data = aaa;
    by year;
run;
```

and then your proc boxplot should work as written.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for replying.
Yes, I have tried that. 
However, the variable ID will not be in increasing order if I were to sort by year.
As such, I still cannot get my desired output.

Comment: You can sort by multiple variables. So "by year id" instead of "by year"

Comment: Actually, the data I have posted here is not complete. What I have on hand is a bigger dataset, the problem is I cannot sort both ID and year in an increasing manner.

Comment: Thanks for "by year id"; It works, however, the output is still not good enough for boxplot. The year is sorted, like 2007 2007 2007 2008 2008 2008, but the corresponding id is like 1 1 2 1 1 2. The id is still not continuously increasing, thus cannot be used for boxplot.

Comment: What do you mean by "not good enough?" It sounds like this is more a problem with your underlying data than your boxplots; maybe try a stacked bar chart or something if boxplots aren't what you want to use

Comment: Means I still cannot get the boxplot output I want.
Please refer to my earlier comment,if the problem is my dataset. So I guess there is no other way to go around this?

Comment: What is your end goal? One plot for each year sorted by id, one plot for each id sorted by year?

Comment: My end goal is one single box plot consisting of 4 boxes side by side.
I just realised I should not use "by" statement, it will give me separate boxplots.

Comment: Something like. One single plot, something like [link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/w7rF1.png)

Answer (score 1):

This is quite easy to do with `sgplot`, which is part of the newer `ODS Graphics` suite which is available in base SAS.

```
proc sgplot data=sashelp.cars;
  vbox mpg_city/category=type group=origin grouporder=ascending;
run;
```

You would use `category=id` and `group=year`  in your example data - you get one separate tick on the x axis for each `category` and then you get a separate bar clustered together for each `group`.

Comment: many thanks for your help! Will try out tmr when I'm back in school lab.