# How to create Boxplot in SAS

Tags: sas, boxplot

I need to create charts just as shown on this image :

[image]

```
Resp_ID,Score,Country,Year
P004001,50,Singapore,2007
P004001,60,Australia,2008
P004002,90,Australia,2009
P004002,80,Singapore,2010
P004003,70,Australia,2007
P004004,90,Australia,2008
P004004,90,Australia,2009
P004005,70,Singapore,2010
P004005,55,Australia,2007
P004005,65,Australia,2008
P004006,96,Australia,2009
P004007,80,Singapore,2010
P004007,90,Australia,2007
P004008,85,Australia,2008
P004008,40,Singapore,2009
P004009,75,Australia,2010
P004010,55,Australia,2007
P004010,85,Singapore,2008
P004011,70,Australia,2009
P004011,60,Singapore,2010
```

Please help on this as I'm having almost no idea of graphs and looking for quick solution.

```
axis1 order = (0 to 100 by 10) label=none;
axis2  label=none value=none major=none minor=none style=1;

proc boxplot data=Graph_2_INTRIM;
format score 8.;
plot score*Country_Name (Year) / vaxis=axis1 haxis=axis2 BLOCKPOS=4     CBLOCKVAR=(COLORCODE) ;
run;
```

But I'm not getting two Category Variable on my HAXIS

Comment: This is not a 'write code for free' service. You should make an attempt to solve your problem yourself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Boxplot in SAS using proc gchart](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36720178/boxplot-in-sas-using-proc-gchart)

Comment: I tried but not getting desire result. I used this code       axis1 order = (0 to 100 by 10) label=none;
axis2  label=none value=none major=none minor=none style=1;

proc boxplot data=Graph_2_INTRIM;
format score 8.;
plot score*Country_Name (Year) / vaxis=axis1 haxis=axis2 BLOCKPOS=4 CBLOCKVAR=(COLORCODE) ;
run;